# Relative speed of sound (relativistic velocities)

Tags: waves, acoustics, speed

This question is about waves speed, not about waves frequency shift (I already know about Doppler's effect).

I know that for all the mechanical waves, e.g. sound,  the perceived wave speed depends on the relative speed of the observer with respect to the medium.

In order to calculate this perceived speed in the most general case (including possibly relativistic speed of the observer with respect to the medium), must I use the RELATIVISTIC velocity addition (adding "wave speed with respect to medium" plus "speed of the observer with respect to medium") instead of CLASSIC velocity addition?

Comment: This is not really an answer, but as a practical matter, I've spent a career doing signal processing in acoustics, sonar and radar, and people in those fields don't bother to take relativity into account.  It's just too small of an effect to matter at the velocities in question.

Comment: @david thank you. I guess all depends on the velocity of the observer relative to the medium. I am looking for a "theoretical" answer, but thank you anyway for your "practical" one

Comment: Calculate the speed difference caused by SR effects, and then calculate the temperature difference leading to the same speed difference. Then consider real temperature fluctuations due advective and thermal convection, adiabatic changes and turbulence.